# The java file is not recognizing the layout file of the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to use fragments in my android application. I am creating a fragment. However, the problem is that the Java portion of the code is not able to recognize the layout file. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you importing the Resources class (`import <yourpackage>.R;`) ? Another cause of this is whether your Resources class are not up to date, a Clean Project or Rebuild should solve.

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada Tried rebuilding the project without much help. I couldn't clearly understand what you meant by importing the resources class. I right-clicked on the package and then from "new"  got a new fragment.

Comment: In Java programming, you need to import other class to use in yours. Every resource item has an identifier in [Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) class (generated automatically). However, you can use the Androis Studio helper to maybe fix this, put the cursor on the error code and type `Alt+Enter`, a suggestion should appear, if be availiable. If nothing this help you, I suggest read the documentation about Resources in Android Docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do following steps

```
1. Build -> Clean Project

2. Build -> Rebuild Project

3. Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

Comment: Yes, it worked when I restarted Android Studio. Thanks.